# Is the time complexity of this code O(N^2)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, substring, time-complexity

This is a solution of mine for one of the problems in leetcode. Through my deductions, I concluded it to have an overall O(N^2) time complexity. However, I would like to get a confirmation on this just so that I don't continue making the same mistakes when it comes to judging the time/space complexity of an algorithm.

Oh, and the problem goes as follows:

> Given an input string, reverse the string word by word.
>   e.g. "I am you" == "you am I"

The code is as follows:-

```
public String reverseWords(String s) {
        //This solution is in assumption that I am restricted to a one-pass algorithm.
        //This can also be done through a two-pass algorithm -- i.e. split the string and etc.

        if(null == s)
            return "";
        //remove leading and trailing spaces
        s = s.trim();
        int lengthOfString = s.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Keeps track of the number of characters that have passed.
        int passedChars = 0;
        int i = lengthOfString-1;
        for(; i >= 0; i--){
            if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
                //Appends the startOfWord and endOfWord according to passedChars.
                sb.append(s.substring(i+1, (i+1+passedChars))).append(" ");
                //Ignore additional space chars.
                while(s.charAt(i-1) == ' '){
                    i--;
                }
                passedChars = 0;
            }else{
                passedChars++;
            }
        }

        //Handle last reversed word that have been left out.
        sb.append(s.substring(i+1, (i+1+passedChars)));

        //return reversedString;
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

My reasoning for this being an O(N^2) algorithm:-

1. The loop = O(n)
2. StringBuilder.append = O(1)
3. Substring method = O(n) [as of Java 7]

On that note, if anyone else has a better solution than this, please feel free to share it! :)

I was aiming for a one-pass solution and therefore, opted out of splitting the string before the loop.

Appreciate the help!

**EDIT:** I meant to ask about the time complexity of the portion of the code that contains the loop. I apologize in advance if the question was misleading/confusing. The whole chunk of code is meant for clarification purposes. :)

Comment: Abstract time complexity calculation depends entirely on what you count as 1 operation.

Comment: And it could be done in linear time and linear space if you count accessing or copying one letter as your basic operation.

Comment: Does it need to handle Unicode correctly? Where do the dots have to go to? Do you have a full specificcation with more examples?

Comment: @biziclop Hi! Thanks for the advice. I have edited my original post to clarify on which portion of the code that I was most curious about -- in terms of time complexity. And could you further explain what you meant by solving the problem in linear time/space?

Comment: @Thomas Hi! Nope. You don't have to worry about handling Unicode. The code that I have provided was an accepted solution so no worries about it being incorrect. :) I am just curious regarding the time complexity of the "loop" portion of the code. The full specs/problem can be found on leetcode under the "Reverse Words in a String" title.

Comment: And just for fun: `String.join( " ", Collections.reverse( Arrays.asList( input.split( " " ))));`

Comment: @biziclop D: That's actually awesome. Built-in functions FTW!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time complexity is `O(n)`.

Each insertion (`append(x)`) to a `StringBuilder` is done in `O(|x|)`, where |x| is the size of the input string you are appending. (independent of the state of the builder, on average).

Your algorithm iterates the entire string, and use `String#substring()` for each word in it. Since the words do not overlap, it means you do a `substring()` for each word one time, and append it to the builder (also once) - giving you `2|x|` for each word `x`.

Summing it up, gives you

```
T(S) = |S| + sum{2|x| for each word x}
```

But since `sum{|x| for each word x} <= |S|`, this gives you total of:

```
T(S) = |S| + 2sum{|x| for each word x} = |S| + 2|S| = 3|S|
```

Since |S| is the size of the input (`n`), this is `O(n)`

---

Note that the important part is in jdk7, the `substring()` method is linear in the size of the output string, not the original one (you copy only the relevant part, not all of the string).

Comment: Hi! Terrific answer. However, I do have a few questions if you don't mind:-
1) Isn't appending to Java's StringBuilder done in O(1) due to its amortized time complexity?

Comment: Whoops, got cut off there. 2) How did you get the 2|x| value for substring()? Are you referring to the size of stringbuilder's current buffer and the substring portion of the original string?

Comment: @cottonman the `append()` is done in linear time to the input size. It takes a charsequence, and copy it to the builder. This copy is `O(|x|)`, it is however, independent in the size of the state of the builder (what you already "built"), on average. So, adding a very long string won't be `O(1)`, it will be linear in the size of that added string. But adding a constant number of characters, will be O(1). Hope it clears.

Comment: Appending x characters to a `StringBuilder` takes O(x) time simply because you need to copy x characters. A quick note, to make things clearer in the implementation, the `StringBuilder` should be initialised with a size parameter, since we know the output will be at most as long as the input.

Comment: the 2|x| is from (1) the `substring()`, which is O(|x|), and (2) From appending to the builder, which is also `O(|x|)`.

Comment: Also note, the complexity calculation is a bit simplification, since we actually needed to multiply all by some constant (the substring is `O(|x|)`, not `|x|`). This simplification is for clarity, and it does not affect the answer, only makes it more readable, as we don't need to multiply everything by some constant.

Comment: @amit Oh! I understand now. Much thanks for the clarification! I was sorta blinded by the substring() method that I jumped to a quadratic complexity conclusion and I overlooked the fact that I was actually substring-ing a word at a time (without repetitions!)

Comment: @biziclop Thanks for clarification! And yeah, I should have initialized the size of the builder since the length has already been established. Will keep that in mind the next time I use StringBuilder! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution which I believe may perform a little better.

```
public String reverseWords(String s) {
    String[] array = s.split(" ");
    int len = array.length;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(" ").append(array[len - i - 1]);
    }

    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: The question is not how to do it more efficiently, it's about the time complexity of the suggested algorithm. This is a good answer, for a different question, I am afraid..

Comment: quote from the question: "On that note, if anyone else has a better solution than this, please feel free to share it! :)"

Comment: How do you know it's better without establishing the complexity of the original algorithm? :)

Comment: @pnadczuk Hi! That is indeed a good solution! Quick question; Would you consider this to be a 2-pass algorithm due to the use of the split() method? I was sorta aiming for a 1-pass solution and therefore, opted not to use the split() method. However, if the 2-pass solution is more efficient, I am open to altering my original solution! :)

Comment: Oww, I missed the comment about 1-pass! Unfortunately I would consider it to be 2-pass :(. Moreover, your algorithm is a O(n) indeed, and works very well on long strings :-)

Comment: You only read the original string once but you copy each character twice. So I guess that makes it a 1.5-pass algorithm :). Asymptotically they're all linear time solutions.

Comment: By the way, `split()` is generally quite an expensive operation as it requires compiling a regex pattern, initialising a matcher and so on. Except in the Oracle implementation there's a shortcut for single (non-special) character patterns, which does a simple loop similar to what's in OP's solution.

Comment: @biziclop - thats true. It can be easily visualized by replacing " " with "\\s". Operation time nearly doubles!

Comment: @pnadczuk No worries! It is always nice to see alternative solutions. Helps in the learning process. :D

Answer (score 1):

Amit has already given you detailed explanation on the complexity computation, I would like to give you a simpler version.

In general, if we have nested loops, we consider the complexity to be O(N^2). But this is not the case always, as you have to do some activity n times for each nth part of input. E.g., if you have input of size 3, you have to do some action 3 times on each of the element. Then, you can say that your algorithm has O(n^2) complexity.

Since you are traversing and processing each part of your input string only once (even though you are using nested loops), complexity should be on the order of O(n). For proof, Amit has done quite a job.

Although, I would have used below code to reverse the order of words

```
String delim = " ";
String [] words = s.split(delim);
int wordCount = words.length; 

for(int i = 0; i < wordCount / 2; i++) {
    String temp = words[i];
    words[i] = words[wordCount - i - 1];
    words[wordCount - i - 1] = temp;
}

String result = Arrays.toString(words).replace(", ", delim).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```

Comment: Hi! Your explanation did indeed help me further understand the reasoning from Amit. So, thanks for that and for your code as well. :)